# AWS Cognito, amplify - name attribute not displaying with currentauthenticateduser

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to display the user's name attribute that is associated with the AWS account using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser but cannot get it to work. The attributes are showing in the console log but 'name' is coming back as undefined. If I take 'name' out, there is no longer an error but there is also no text displaying on the screen.

I cannot figure out why it seems to be reading userInfo.attributes but not userInfo.attributes.name.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

const ProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const userInfo = Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

  userInfo.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
 })

  return (

      <ScrollView>
        <View>
              <Text>
                {userInfo.attributes.name}
              </Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default ProfileScreen;
```

Comment: ```{userInfo && userInfo.attributes.name}```?